# Can you switch between different material versions?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

So I have a model that has two different shading versions. The usual principle bsdf and emission for a shadeless render. Using mixer nodes makes it easier to switch between the shaders in nodes but I still have to go through each material to update the mix node. Is there an easier way to switch shaders?

Comment: could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: @moonboots https://imgur.com/a/HqxvvE4
It's just one material with two shader nodes into a mixernode. Could I do this for several materials to quickly switch shaders without going through each material? Do I have to make a keyframe or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add a driver** to the ***Fac*** (mix factor) of the ***Mix Shader nodes***. Use a *Custom Property* or the X-value of the position of another object to control the driver. If you change the value (0 or 1) then the driver(s) will update the *Fac* value for you and you can switch between all materials with a single click.

**Example with Custom Property**

- create a new *Customer Property*. You can use any object like the camera or an Empty. I used Suzanne the monkey in this example because *Custom Properties* of an Empty are not displayed in the side-panel ("N-panel") of the viewport, just in the *Object Properties* panel under the *Custom Properties* section.
- Enter `0` or `1` (no trailing .000) for the *Property value* and *Default Value* and give it a proper name ("Shadeless" in the example). If you change the name later you need to update all drivers manually.

[image: new property values]

- Right-click the value of the new property and select "*Copy as New Driver*"
- In the shading editor, right-click the ***Fac*** value of the *Mix Shader node*, select "*Paste Driver*"
- repeat the last step and paste the driver in all materials that you want to switch

Finally, to switch it, select Suzanne and change the value of the custom property.

[image: the switch in action]

Comment: I tried yours because it was the most in depth of the three solutions and it worked like a charm. Although I was worried at first because when I tried to copy-paste the driver from the n-panel properties onto the mix node my blender 2.91.2.0 would always crash. But thankfully it worked from the object properties. Thank you so much, Blunder!
https://i.imgur.com/yBph1Kg.gif

Answer (score 3):

A bit dirty but you could use a node group:

Select the *Mix Shader* that you use as a shutter, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to create a group. Once done, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into the group and unplug the factor socket that will be created by default. If you play with the factor value it will switch from a shader to another:

[image]

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to go out. In all your other materials create the group you've created with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and plug the shaders:

[image]

Now select one of these groups and play with the *Mix Shader* factor value, it will switch all the other material *Mix Shaders* as well.

Comment: why dirty? I think it is pretty clean, if you give the group node a good name like "color all nodes" or something ;)

Comment: I don't remember, I guess I expected a more direct way to do it  ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your model is one object..

You could use the *Object* tab > *Relations* panel > *Pass Index*, or some function of it, as a switch. It's called 'Object Index' in the *Object Info* node:

[image]